# Deep Q learning not performing well for algo-trading

Tags: python-3.x, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have implemented a deep q learning in Python using keras framework to reproduce a paper's results. However, It is not working. Here is some info :

1. the training is done in 10000 step for the agent for 2 possible actions
2. the input vector's shape is 117
3. Here is the code for the algorithm (inspired from various github repos maybe I implemented the algorithm wrong)

```
def build_dqn(lr, n_actions, input_dims, fc1_dims, fc2_dims,CLIP_GRADIENT=1):

    #set_seed(42)

    model = Sequential([
                Dense(fc1_dims, input_shape=(input_dims,)),  #     bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)
                Activation('relu'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                Dense(fc2_dims),
                Activation('relu'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                Dense(n_actions)])

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr, clipvalue=CLIP_GRADIENT), loss='mse')

    return model

class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha, gamma, n_actions, epsilon, batch_size,
                 input_dims, epsilon_dec=0.996,  epsilon_end=0.01,
                 mem_size=1000000, fname='dqn_model.h5'):
        self.action_space = [i for i in range(n_actions)]
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.epsilon_dec = epsilon_dec
        self.epsilon_min = epsilon_end
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.model_file = fname
        self.memory = ReplayBuffer(mem_size, input_dims, n_actions,
                                   discrete=True)
        self.q_eval = build_dqn(alpha, n_actions, input_dims, 64, 32)

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, new_state, done):
        self.memory.store_transition(state, action, reward, new_state, done)

    def choose_action(self, state):
        state = state[np.newaxis, :]
        rand = np.random.random()
        if rand < self.epsilon:
            action = np.random.choice(self.action_space)
        else:
            actions = self.q_eval.predict(state)
            action = np.argmax(actions)

        return action

    def learn(self):
        if self.memory.mem_cntr > self.batch_size:
            state, action, reward, new_state, done = \
                                          self.memory.sample_buffer(self.batch_size)

            action_values = np.array(self.action_space, dtype=np.int8)
            action_indices = np.dot(action, action_values)

            q_eval = self.q_eval.predict(state)

            q_next = self.q_eval.predict(new_state)

            q_target = q_eval.copy()

            batch_index = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)

            q_target[batch_index, action_indices] = reward + \
                                  self.gamma*np.max(q_next, axis=1)*done

            _ = self.q_eval.fit(state, q_target, verbose=0)

            self.epsilon = self.epsilon*self.epsilon_dec if self.epsilon > \
                           self.epsilon_min else self.epsilon_min
    
    def processState(self, state): 
        n = len(state)
        relative_diff_matrix,prev_posiion = state[:n-1],state[n-1]
        relative_diff_matrix = relative_diff_matrix.reshape((int(n/30),30))
        relative_diff_matrix = np.diff(relative_diff_matrix) / relative_diff_matrix[:,:-1] 
        relative_diff_matrix = StandardScaler().fit_transform(relative_diff_matrix.T).T
        processed_state = relative_diff_matrix.flatten()
        processed_state = np.append(processed_state,prev_posiion)
        return processed_state
    
    def processReward(self, reward,rewardClipping=1):
        return np.clip(reward, -rewardClipping, rewardClipping)
    
    def train_model(self,trainingEnv, n_episodes = 1,verbose=0): 

        scores = []
        eps_history = []

        for i in range(n_episodes):
          done = False
          score = 0
          observation = env.reset()
          observation = self.processState(observation)
          #observation = self.processState(observation)
          while not done:
              action = agent.choose_action(observation)
              observation_, reward, done, info = trainingEnv.step(action)
              
              # Remembering episode
              reward = self.processReward(reward)
              observation_ = self.processState(observation_)
              score += reward
              

              self.remember(observation_, action, reward, observation_, int(done))

            
              # Remembering episode for other action => Better exploration
              otherAction = int(not bool(action))
              otherReward = self.processReward(info['Reward'])
              otherNextState = self.processState(info['State'])
              otherDone = info['Done']
              self.remember(observation_, otherAction, otherReward, otherNextState, otherDone)
              observation = observation_
              
              # learning
              self.learn()

          if verbose :
          
            eps_history.append(agent.epsilon)
            scores.append(score)

            avg_score = np.mean(scores[max(0, i-100):(i+1)])
            print('episode: ', i,'score: %.2f' % score,
                  ' average score %.2f' % avg_score)
                      
              

        trainingEnv.render()


    def save_model(self):
        self.q_eval.save(self.model_file)

    def load_model(self):
        self.q_eval = load_model(self.model_file)
```

I start with 100 $ capital I finish with slightly more or less in the horizon of 20  years (about 10000 step). I tried tuning the parameters but nothing worked.

here is the main:

```
env = TradingEnv(marketSymbol="GOOGL", period=PERIOD_DEFAULT, startingDate=START_DEFAULT, endingDate=END_DEFAULT, columns=COLUMNS, money=100,transactionCosts=0)
lr = 0.0005
agent = Agent(gamma=1, epsilon=0.00, alpha=lr, input_dims=117,
              n_actions=2, mem_size=1000000, batch_size=32, epsilon_end=0.0)
agent.train_model(env)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to solve the problem. We need to set the number of episodes to a sufficiently high number (not 1), in my case it was just thirty. However, I don't know how to efficiently backtest the deep q trading agent !